# Android - How to set a bookmark in webview content?

Tags: android, text, webview, bookmarks

I have been trying to set a bookmark in my webview text. But cant find any help regarding this. Please guide me how to do it

```
String html = "<html><head></head><body>"+text1+"</body></html>";  
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Comment: add a bookmark to where? make your point more clearer

Comment: You could have a database and maintain the web view book mark yourself

Comment: i need to add bookmarks in webview in my application. which reads a pdf file then displays text in webview. Now i want to select text and add a bookmark for the selected text

Comment: @farhan did you find any solution, please let me know if you find out it. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

refer this project, in this browser he showed first page with most recent bookmarks and recent history. with help of html files and java.

https://github.com/darvin/zirco-browser

Comment: brother thanks for the response but i need to add bookmarks in webview in my application. which reads a pdf file then displays text in webview. Now i want to select text and add a bookmark for the selected text